# Flink connect streams using KeyedCoProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

For 1:1 joining, I'm using KeyedCoProcessFunction, I have two streams, lookup stream (100 records per second) and clickstream stream(10000 records per second). In `processElement2` method, I'm looking for the key in `MapState<Long,Row>`, if found, enriching clickstream data with it else setting this record to side output, and later sinking side output to kafka. I haven't used any window on both input streams. For the dlq topic in kakfa, continuously I'm seeing 1-2 records getting produced per second, how can I somehow wait for a few ms for lookup id in `processElement2` method before pushing that to side output.

```
val joinStream = lookDataStream.keyBy(row -> row.<Long>getFieldAs("id"))
            .connect(clickDataStream.keyBy(row -> row.<Long>getFieldAs("lookupid")))
            .process(new EnrichJoinFunction());
public static class EnrichJoinFunction
      extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row> {


    final OutputTag<Row> outputTag = new OutputTag<Row>("side-output") {};

    private MapState<Long, Row> map = null;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
      val MapStateDescriptor =
          new MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row>(
              "state",
              TypeInformation.of(Long.class),
              TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Row>() {}));
      MapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.days(15)).build());
      /*MapStateDescriptor.setQueryable("test");*/
      map = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(MapStateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement1(
        Row lookupRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
        throws Exception {
      log.debug("Received Lookup Record" + RowUtils.printRow(lookupRow));
      val id = lookupRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");
      if (!map.contains(id)) {
        map.put(id, lookupRow);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(
        Row clickRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
        throws Exception {
      log.debug("Received Click stream Record" + RowUtils.printRow(clickRow));

      val id = clickRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");

      if (map.contains(id)) {
          // enrich join
          val joinRow = join(clickRow, map.get(id));
          out.collect(joinRow);
      } else {
        // lookup entry not yet arrived, send it to side output - dlq
        ctx.output(outputTag, clickRow);
      }
    }

    public Row join(Row clickRow, Row lookupRow) throws ParseException {
      Row joinedRow = new Row(RowKind.INSERT, 13);
      // row setter join ouput
      return joinedRow;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TimerService](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#timers) to achieve this.

So, the idea is to store the clickstream rows which don't have immediatly matching lookup data in a dedicated `MapState<Long,Row>`  and register `processingTimeTimer/eventTimeTimer` timer which will be triggered some time later. On timer callback, you can try to join lookup data and clickstream data there. If no match found again, then finally send this click event to side output.

It might look as follow:

```
public static class EnrichJoinFunction
      extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row> {


    final OutputTag<Row> outputTag = new OutputTag<Row>("side-output") {};

    private MapState<Long, Row> map = null;
    private MapState<Long, Row> clickstreamState = null;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
      MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row> MapStateDescriptor =
          new MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row>(
              "state",
              TypeInformation.of(Long.class),
              TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Row>() {}));
      MapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.days(15)).build());
      /*MapStateDescriptor.setQueryable("test");*/
      map = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(MapStateDescriptor);

      MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row> clickstreamStateMapStateDescriptor =
          new MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row>(
              "clickstreamState",
              TypeInformation.of(Long.class),
              TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Row>() {}));
      clickstreamState MapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(1)).build());
      clickstreamState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(clickstreamStateMapStateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement1(
        Row lookupRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
        throws Exception {
      log.debug("Received Lookup Record" + RowUtils.printRow(lookupRow));
      Long id = lookupRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");
      if (!map.contains(id)) {
        map.put(id, lookupRow);
      }

      // join immediately any matching click events, waiting for counterpart
      if (clickstreamState.contains(id)) {
          // enrich join
          Row joinRow = join(clickstreamState.get(id), lookupRow);
          out.collect(joinRow);
          clickstreamState.remove(id)
      } 
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement2(
        Row clickRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
        throws Exception {
      log.debug("Received Click stream Record" + RowUtils.printRow(clickRow));

      Long id = clickRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");

      if (map.contains(id)) {
          // enrich join
          Row joinRow = join(clickRow, map.get(id));
          out.collect(joinRow);
      } else {
        // put in state and check in 1 second
        clickstreamState.put(id, clickRow)
        Long currTimestamp = ctx.timestamp()
        ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(currTimestamp + 1000)
      }
    }

    public Row join(Row clickRow, Row lookupRow) throws ParseException {
      Row joinedRow = new Row(RowKind.INSERT, 13);
      // row setter join ouput
      return joinedRow;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(
      Long timestamp,
      KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out
    ) {
       Long id = ctx.getCurrentKey
       Row clickRow = clickstreamState.get(id)
       if (map.contains(id)) {
          // enrich join
          val joinRow = join(clickRow, map.get(id));
          out.collect(joinRow);
       } else {
          // lookup entry not arrived even in 1 second, send it to side output - dlq
          ctx.output(outputTag, clickRow);
       }
       clickstreamState.remove(id)
  }
}}
```

Comment: Long currTimestamp = ctx.timestamp(), i'm getting null, as don't have watermark for input stream, can I use System.currentTimeMillis?

Comment: @gauravmiglani, I would say yes in case you end up with processing time steam characteristic as it relies on the time of the local machine

Comment: cool, also one more thing, even after one second, if lookup entry not yet arrived, i don't want to send it to dlq but register another timer to check again in 1 sec, instead  of ctx.output(outputTag, clickRow), can i write ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(currTimestamp + 1000) inside onTimer Method

Comment: to be honest, I haven't done so but you can try, it might work.
Alternatively, what I would suggest if you are going to join it anyway, you can register initially a timer for a long time for maximum time you can wait, but on the same time add a check in `processElement1` function for matching click event in state - if it's there, then join in `processElement1` and remove the timer and event from state. This way you wouldn't need to constantly retrigger the timer.

Comment: I don't understand, can you please explain it via code edits

Comment: @gauravmiglani, I mean, you can perform the same join as in processElement2` in `processElement1` as well, i.e. once lookup event comes, check matching click events in state and if has match, then join and remove the timer. This way there is no sense in triggering timer service every second

Comment: but this way, there will be latency in the output, as there might be case lookup events stop arriving from the input stream for let's suppose 1 hrs, then for 1 hr, I haven't processed any clickstream record

Comment: No, `processElement2` will be invoked whenever the new event comes. I've edited the answer with the join code in `processElement1`

Comment: No, processElement2 will be invoked whenever the new event comes.-> are you talking about event from either of any one input, correct me if I'm wrong, do both methods processElement1, processElement2 triggers if any event arrives in one of the input in the connect stream?

Comment: processElement1 triggers whenever the lookup event comes, processElement2 triggers whenever the click event comes, but they are not blocking each other

Comment: got it, since multiple clickstream can arrive with same lookup id, changing clickstreamState data type from MapState<Long, Row> to MapState<Long, List<Row>> and joining all rows in processElement1, am i right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @gauravmiglani could you please accept the answer if it solves the original question?

Comment: not sure of NPE, do you have any idea for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021083/npe-in-flink-keyedcoprocessfunction

Comment: Timers are costly operations if your application/job is latency sensitive, else this will serve your requirement