# NPE in Flink KeyedCoProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using KeyedCoProcessFunction on connected stream, both streams are keyed by `id`, also I'm using MapState and putting a value of type list if the key doesn't exist, and I'm checking for the existence of key as well in `processElement2`, so ideally there is no chance of NPE, but still getting it.

```
val joinStream = lookDataStream.keyBy(row -> row.<Long>getFieldAs("id"))
        .connect(clickDataStream.keyBy(row -> row.<Long>getFieldAs("lookupid")))
        .process(new EnrichJoinFunction());

public static class EnrichJoinFunction
  extends KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row> {


final OutputTag<Row> outputTag = new OutputTag<Row>("side-output") {};

private MapState<Long, Row> map = null;
private MapState<Long, List<Row>> clickstreamState = null;

@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
  MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row> MapStateDescriptor =
      new MapStateDescriptor<Long, Row>(
          "state",
          TypeInformation.of(Long.class),
          TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Row>() {}));
  MapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.days(15)).build());
  map = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(MapStateDescriptor);

  MapStateDescriptor<Long, List<Row>> clickstreamStateMapStateDescriptor =
      new MapStateDescriptor<Long, List<Row>>(
          "clickstreamState",
          TypeInformation.of(Long.class),
          TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<Row>>() {}));
  clickstreamState MapStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(5).build());
  clickstreamState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(clickstreamStateMapStateDescriptor);
}

@Override
public void processElement1(
    Row lookupRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
    throws Exception {
  log.debug("Received Lookup Record" + RowUtils.printRow(lookupRow));
  Long id = lookupRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");
  if (!map.contains(id)) {
    map.put(id, lookupRow);
  }

  // join immediately any matching click events, waiting for counterpart
  if (clickstreamState.contains(id)) {
    for (Row curRow : clickstreamState.get(id)) {
      // enrich join
      Row joinRow = join(clickstreamState.get(id), lookupRow);
      out.collect(joinRow);
    }
    clickstreamState.remove(id);
  } 
}

@Override
public void processElement2(
    Row clickRow, KeyedCoProcessFunction<Long, Row, Row, Row>.Context ctx, Collector<Row> out)
    throws Exception {
  log.debug("Received Click stream Record" + RowUtils.printRow(clickRow));

  Long id = clickRow.<Long>getFieldAs("id");

  if (map.contains(id)) {
      // enrich join
      Row joinRow = join(clickRow, map.get(id));
      out.collect(joinRow);
  } else {
    if (clickstreamState.contains(id)) {
      List<Row> rows = clickstreamState.get(id);
      if (rows != null) {
        rows.add(clickRow);
      } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("This exception should never throw NPE");
      }
    } else {
      val clickList = new ArrayList<Row>();
      clickList.add(clickRow);
      clickstreamState.put(id, clickList);
    }
  }
}

public Row join(Row clickRow, Row lookupRow) throws ParseException {
  Row joinedRow = new Row(RowKind.INSERT, 13);
  // row setter join ouput
  return joinedRow;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the exception ? At what line it happens ? How often it happens ? One guess might be that the state ttl expired in between the `contains` and `get` calls. However, this is rather unlikely

Comment: throw new NullPointerException("This exception should never throw NPE");

Comment: Ideally, since in the else block, I'm initializing the array list, so the get value shouldn't be null anytime.

Comment: Could you try `clickstreamState.put(id, new ArrayList<Row>());` instead of `clickstreamState.remove(id);` in `processElement1` ?

Comment: same error, should I try with thread-safe list instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally I think the implementation is flawed. When your `processElement1` and `processElement2` methods are called, the operator's state is already scoped to the key value. So there's no need for a `MapState<id, Row>` or `MapState<id, List<Row>>` state, you just want `ValueState<Row>` and `ListState<Row>`.